# Execute 'fc -ln -1' (bash history) in node.js spawn

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I've been searching for an answer and I couldn't find one (perhaps I'm not searching well). The issue is as follows:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var proc = spawn('fc', ['-ln', '-1']);

proc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data.toString('utf-8'));
});

proc.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Error: ' + data.toString('utf-8'));
});

proc.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log(code);
});
```

When I run this node script, it outputs '0' and nothing else. Apparently `spawn` works, but it doesn't output the history. I've tried with many combinations, but `fc` command simply doesn't output anything. I've also tried with exec and execSync. Neither output anything.

Is there a way to get the bash history from node.js? What am I missing?

### Update:

According to [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/histcommands.html), bash history commands can't be output inside a shell script. That might mean that from spawned child processes, it still holds true. I gave up trying to get the last used command, since [Etan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) made me realize that there's no easy way to tell the "last used command" in interactive multi sessions. I am now trying to read the $HISTFILE shell var (history file location) from inside Node with no luck yet.

Any ideas?

### Update 2:

I just hardcoded most used shells history routes (bash, zsh, fish) and read the file directly. However I'll leave this open since I learned a lot about shell scripting, and hopefully this will help someone else. The key vars to use in Node (at least in Mac) are `process.env.SHELL` and `process.env.HOME`, to build the file route.

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? Why do you want to get the bash history? Non-interactive shells don't generally *have* history.

Comment: I'm trying to get the last command that was executed in the shell to log it down to a file. The code example I provided is oversimplified to try to understand why this command doesn't work.

Comment: In *what* shell? The last shell session that ended? The most recently executed command in whichever shell session happens to have written to the history file last (if they are set to write to the file in "real time")? Is your code executing the shell command you are trying to log?

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite get what you're trying to explain to me, since as I get it, you're saying that Node.js .spawn() method creates a "shell" on it's own. What I'm trying to do is, for instance, if a user types `pwd` in a console window, then when I run the Node.js script in the same console, I want to be able to log `pwd`. Is there a way to do so from Node.js?

Comment: Yes. `spawn` is creating a new shell session. How else would it work? Whose shell history are you trying to interact with here?

Comment: You can read the shell's history file manually if you want but I still don't understand *why* you want to do this.

Comment: I just edited my last comment for me to be more clear.

Comment: I thought of reading manually the history file, but then it won't work if I hardcode the history file location, if for instance, my node app user uses zsh instead of bash. The reason I'm trying to log that value is for a proof of concept, for me to be able to get the value and store it in a file, using node.js

Comment: It is probably possible to get `fc` to return values to you but as I said you are running in your own shell session when you do this. "The last command run" isn't as clear as you think it is for a user who can have multiple sessions running at once. etc.

Comment: I've been fiddling around to try to get the $HISTFILE var from Node.js in order to get the last line of it (As you said, it doesn't make much sense on multiple sessions), but I am still unable to get it from Node. Any ideas on how to do so?

Comment: It probably isn't being set in a non-interactive session. You'll need to force an interactive session to be started (and no I don't know how to do that here, it is the `-i` flag to bash, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway. I'll keep looking into it.